# UICollectionView crash in [_UIFlowLayoutSection updateEstimatedSizeForSection] in iOS9 - Xcode7

Tags: ios, autolayout, uicollectionview, ios9, uicollectionviewcell

I try to using auto-layout with `UICollectionViewCell`. [Demo project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bb1dlcxjtqokewc/AutoLayout.zip?dl=0) runs fine on iOS8 but crash on iOS9. I try debug deeper but cannot find any reason. Xcode stop at `[_UIFlowLayoutSection updateEstimatedSizeForSection]`

Any idea?

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue

Answer (score 0):

I just downloaded your project. First of all goto your storyboard and click on your label, in identifier pane change the tag value to something like 100.

In your cellForItemAtIndexPath Function replace present implementation with

```
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(String("LabelCell"), forIndexPath: indexPath)
let str = "dsadasdadaddsfsf"
let len = Int(rand()) % str.characters.count
let label = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(100) as! UILabel;
label.text = str.substringToIndex(str.startIndex.advancedBy(len))
cell.setNeedsLayout()
cell.layoutIfNeeded()
return cell
```

Finally comment out line number 33 in your view controller class

Comment: First, the outlet label is valid.
Second, how does the auto-layout work without line 33?